# Creating an NSTableView and custom NSViewController programmatically

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsscrollview, nsviewcontroller

Having no trouble creating an NSTableView in Interface Builder and connecting it to a subclass of NSViewController for its data (instantiated in the Interface Builder Objects section).

Now I want to create the NSTableView and NSViewController programmatically, but I'm having trouble figuring out how (I'm new to Cocoa).  What would be the standard approach for this, given that the NSViewController subclass has no nib?

By the way, the reason I want to do this is that I want to create an arbitrary number of small table views that will appear (separated) within a scroll view.  Is this something I'll come to regret?  Would it be better to customize the hell out of a single table view so that it appears to be broken up into various parts, rather than actually having separate table views?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table view like any other object, by using `[[NSTableView alloc] init]`. From there you can create `NSTableColumn` instances the same way, and add them using `addTableColumn:`, and use `setDataSource:` to connect it to the view controller. Then add it to the parent view using `addSubview:`.

Almost anything that can be done in Interface Builder can be done in this kind of programmatic way, although it's usually fiddlier and not recommended if you can help it.

Another approach would be to design a new `NSViewController` subclass to work with the tables, create a separate .xib file for the table view, and instantiate each new table view as needed using `initWithNibName:bundle:`.